# Intel server + windows server 2012 or 2016 SE7520BD2

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, network-attached-storage, intel

I have recently picked up a SE7520BD2 server for essentially no money, I am a student and run a small IT consultancy business with web design and basic pc repair. I plan to use this server as a NAS and VPN server VPN to allow me to access my network at University when i am at home and NAS for backup and media streaming purposes, As I do a little bit of web design, It may come in handy as a test server.

Whenever I try to install 2012 or 2016 (I can get these both for free due to microsoft dreamspark), the installation fails, I see the screen which says loading files, followed by the screen with just the windows logo on. then the server reboots.

I would appreciate any help I can get on this. I am also prepared to think about a linux solution. It would be great to get this server working due to the 6 hotswap bays and the 16gb of ram I can stick in it! It might be that the graphics card is no longer supported??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using all the compatible hardware in the Motherboard?
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/server-products/server-boards/legacy-server-and-workstation-boards/intel-legacy-server-board-family/intel-server-board-se7520bd2.html?_ga=1.123294923.1355009156.1492408488

That motherboard is too old to work with that OS 2012/2012R2/2016. (The OS compatible with this board is windows server 2003 or 2000).
This is the source: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/se7520bd2/sb/se7520bd2se7520bd2d2tholrev20.pdf

Here's the compatibility of the hardware list:
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/server-products/server-boards/000007582.html
Try windows server 2008 R2 on that computer, probably that should work.

If not you should find a windows server 2003 OS and install it.

If you have a powerful desktop you can try a windows 10 pro. that allows you to use the Virtualization feature on it. So in the meantime you could make money to make grow your enterprise. so you can use windows server 2012 or 2016 in a virtual machine on your own desktop computer. (just windows 10 pro).